# How to disable the back key at the time of camera action in windows phone?

Tags: camera, windows-phone-8, jpeg, bounds

I want to disable the windows phone back key at the time of camera action processing.

Because at the time of camera action, i click the back button it's exit from my application.

I publish my app in windows store.

Now this crash report came.

**More Questions**

I don't know why this crashes occurred in my application

MainPage.camera_Completed

Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarItemList_1[[System.__Canon,_mscorlib]].System.Collections.IList.get_Item

Microsoft.Devices.StreamHelper.GetJpegBoundsWithLimit
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure if I understand you correctly. However, it is possible to deactivate the Back-Key in Windows Phone 8.

Just implement the `BackKeyPress`-Event of your Page and set `e.Cancel = true;`

Regards